# React Ant design file upload only xlsx file validation

Tags: reactjs, react-class-based-component

```
  beforeUpload: file => {
      const isPNG = file.type === 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
      if (!isPNG) {
        message.error(`${file.name} is not a XL file`);
      }
      return isPNG || Upload.LIST_IGNORE;
    },
    name: 'file',
    multiple: true,
```

What is the file type for xlsx excel to upload only this i can be able to upload only xls format how to upload both the formats

Comment: const isEXCEL = file.type === 'application/vnd.ms-excel' || file.type === 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet';